# After setting up PayPal Instant Payment Notification, can I resend the IPN for historic transactions retroactively?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have just set up PayPal IPN for my website.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/

[image: IPN Setup]

Unfortunately, someone bought my product before the IPN was set up correctly.

Is there a way to apply the IPN notification to a historic transaction from yesterday that did *not* originally send an IPN?

Comment: What is your IPN script doing that you can't just do manually on that one particular order?  I ever like the idea of telling people to "re-buy" something they've already paid for.  Makes things sloppy.

Comment: @AndrewAngell I agree, but at the moment the scripts and etc. are run through IPN. No "self serve" option.

Comment: But what are the scripts doing that you can't do manually?  Typically it would be updating a database, sending email notifications, etc.  Might be a drag but you can do that manually.  Unfortunately, IPN History won't show anything until after the time it was enabled, so you won't be able to resend that way.

Comment: The issue is in mucking with foreign, unfamiliar scripts for hours while a customer is waiting for their license. Refunding and re-buying with IPN enabled was the quickest resolution for the customer. I will enable manual licensing at some point, but a PayPal feature to "re"-send the IPN would be very helpful.

Comment: They have that feature, but no IPN was ever sent if IPN wasn't enabled in the first place, so there is no ability to "re-send" an IPN that was never sent.

Answer (score 0):

Login to your account at PayPal, find IPN History, find the transaction: you can resend it from there.

Of course if IPN wasn't enabled when they bought, there is nothing to resend.

Comment: You can re-send through "IPN History" for orders that were originally attempted with an IPN. But I cannot find a way to send an *initial* IPN retroactively if no IPN was set up at the time of the order.